# Sharpness of Young's Inequality for Convolutions

Tags: measure-theory, inequality, young-inequality

Young's inequality for convolutions states that for $g\in L^r(\mathbb{R}^d) $ and $f\in L^q(\mathbb{R}^d)$, we have $$\|g*f\|_p\leq \|g\|_r\|f\|_q$$ where $1+\frac{1}{p} = \frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{q}.$

Now if we were to fix g, for example.  Would there be conditions on $f$ that we could impose to ensure we get equality?

If it's not sharp, is it known whether there's an optimal constant in this case that makes it sharp?

Comment: I am not completely sure what you are asking. There are general (sharp) constants $c_{pqr}<1$ for Young's inequality and multidimensional Gaussian give equality with that constant if I remember correctly. You can find this in the book by Lieb and Loss.

Comment: Thanks, you actually did answer my question. And I realized I don't need to know the specific constant, just the fact that it exists, which is nice.

Comment: Glad to hear that I could help :)